# Compiling into CommonJS does not produce files usable by NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

Given the syntax provided [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/03/27/announcing-typescript-1-5-alpha.aspx) (standard ES6 modules with import/export), and the files below, the typescript compiler (tsc) builds files which will throw `Error: Cannot find module` when used with NodeJS.

Here's a stripped down example:

---

#### Input files

src/main.ts

```
import {Example} from 'example';
let e = new Example();
```

src/example.ts

```
export class Example {}
```

---

#### Compilation

Note, using the tsc from `npm install -g typescript`, version `1.5.0-beta`, from a windows machine.

```
tsc --rootDir src --outDir bin
```

---

#### Output files

bin/main.js

```
var example_1 = require('example');
var e = new example_1.Example();
```

bin/example.js

```
var Example = (function () {
    function Example() {
    }
    return Example;
})();
exports.Example = Example;
```

---

Am I doing something incorrectly? I expected `main.js` to include something like `require('example.js')` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> import {Example} from 'example';
> ```

You're importing a module here, not a file. Try

```
import {Example} from './example';
```

Comment: This works, of course. This doesn't seem to match what is provided in the msdn link, however. Is the link incorrect, or am I misreading it?

Comment: Maybe expects that you are installing submodules as modules (`math` in the link)

Comment: Could be, not sure. It looked like they were defining their own math.ts file. Whatever the case, thanks for the response. I can keep working with that pattern.